# Is there a way to select the shortest match on alternation?

Tags: awk, grep, regular-expression

I had the impression that grep and awk used an NFA (Non-Deterministic) regex machine.
The image midway down this page about [Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) confirm that that is the case.

It is known that an NFA implementation could stop when the first alternation is matched. For example, this NFA machine from the linked article [For example, consider the NFA for abab|abbb](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html):

[image]

Which correspond to the regex `abab|abbb` will reach the matching state at the right with the string `ababbbb` when matching the first `abab`. At that point it will stop as it got to the end, to a matching state (S10). No need to test more input, even if another match `abbb` is possible.

That is, in this code:

```
echo 'catfish' | grep -Eo 'cat|catfish'
```

The result should be `cat` but it is `catfish`. No matter if the alternation is swapped, the result is the same.

What makes the grep regex engine always find the longest match?

And, Is it possible to change that default?

Comment: It's a POSIX requirement that the longest match be found for BRE and ERE. You can use perl or `grep -P` (when that's implemented with PCRE like with GNU grep, not ast-open's) for the other alternations not to be considered if a one further on the left matched.

Comment: @mosvy (1) Fact **When you use a Tradition NFA engine, the order of the alternative in an alternation will be respected. This means that if the first alternative lead to a complete successful match, the other alternative will be ignored.** [Link](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/GroupingCapturing)

Comment: @mosvy (1) Also: **Traditional NFA engines run so-called "greedy" match backtracking algorithms, testing all possible expansions of a regular expression in a specific order and accepting the first match.**  Note the word **first**.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978438/dfa-vs-nfa-engines-what-is-the-difference-in-their-capabilities-and-limitations)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a way to do this with a POSIX compliant `grep` or `awk`, because the standard requires the longest match, indeed (see for example the `regex(7)` manpage).

With `awk` you can get the desired output by modifying the `awk` program and the regexp, for instance

```
echo 'SetValue' | awk '{ if (match($0, /Set(Value)?/)) { print substr($0, RSTART, 3); }
```

In this situation I would reach for `pcregrep` (part of the pcre perl compatible regular expression library), which allows you to specify a numbered subgroup with `-o`:

```
echo SetValue | pcregrep -o1 '(Set)(Value)?'
```

or, because pcre has syntax for non-greedy matching,

```
echo SetValue | pcregrep -o0 'Set(Value)??'
```

Comment: Thanks, reasonable description, but you are not using alternation `|` on your regex examples. That is in the title of the question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could make sense of this, it turns out that there are, in fact, [two NFA machines](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/RegularExpressionEngines):

- Traditional NFA engine
  An NFA machine that backtracks and for which *the longest-leftmost match could not always be respected*.
- POSIX NFA engine
  A non-backtracking NFA engine that process all states in parallel and could choose any match in the input string. The selection of the leftmost, longest match is a POSIX requirement.

However a DFA backtracking machine (Perl) that may [blow up exponentially (2^n)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/18280/87113) is driven by the text (not the regex) and could select the first of an alternation (or not).

It is also said that a [DFA recognizes all possible matches in parallel](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/84233/87113).

And, from the author of the article linked in the question, the [re2 implementation defines alternation as: x|y ==> x or y (prefer x)](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) , that is: prefer the first of an alternation.

So, in conclusion, there is no way to actually relate NFAs or DFAs to which part of an alternation will be selected, that depends on the specific implementation.

And, no, I have not found a way to tell a specific implementation to change its default.

Related:

- [time complexity trade offs of nfa vs dfa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32308217/8017719)
- [What is the mathematical difference between a NFA and a DFA](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/12596/87113).
- [Extending Thompson's NFA algorithm with backreferences](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/100675/extending-thompsons-nfa-algorithm-with-backreferences).